# Open a new terminal screen in C ++

Tags: c++

First of all, I have to say that I do not know English exactly. I am improving my English but I am not at a sufficient level yet. Please excuse me for my misspelling and write your answers in the simplest way.

My problem is that I want to run another program made in C ++ when the "1" key is pressed. The files are in the same directory. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your platform which you didn't name. Read this: [ask] and then [Edit] the question. Maybe you want this: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: `system()` should be able to do that mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make cross-platform for your application, use `system` with predefined operating system macros.

For example:

```
#ifdef __FreeBSD__
system("Terminal application object is here");
#endif

#ifdef _WIN64
system("Terminal application object is here");
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to run another program made in C ++

The only standard way to run another program in C++ is the `std::system` function. As per its documentation, this function will call the host environment's shell (also known as command line interpreter). The shell generally has an ability to execute other programs.

However, although `std::system` is standard, the shell itself is not, so any interaction with it will be implementation defined regardless. The use of `std::system` is somewhat problematic in many cases because it can potentially introduce shell injection vulnerability to the program. You should never pass any user input into `std::system`. Given this problem, and the fact that the shell is implementation defined anyway, it is often a good idea to use system specific API to directly execute a program without allowing arbitrary shell commands. How to do that depends on the host environment where the program will run.

Short description of how to do that in POSIX standard systems: First `fork` the process (if you want to stop executing current program entirely and replace with the new one, then you can skip fork), then in the child process call `execv` (or one of its sibling functions).

> when the "1" key is pressed

When using standard input, a C++ program cannot react to a key being pressed. The way it works, you type the input and press enter to submit.

There may be non-standard ways to react to input in a way that you describe which will also be specific to the host environment.